# how to make radio button in option group selected by default in access form

Tags: forms, ms-access-2010

I have an option group in access form. Option group contains 2 radio buttons.How do i make one of the radio button select by default. i tried to set option group Default value =

```
        [ogrp].[DefaultValue]=2
```

It is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make one of the radio button select by default by

```
   Me.OptionGroupname.DefaultValue=1 'DefaultValue= change as required
```